# Where to include JS library in gutenberg blocks

Tags: javascript, block-editor

Lets say that I want to make a block with animations from an external library as [GSAP](https://greensock.com/).

I have this file structure (files not needed omitted):

```
my-blocks-plugin
 │   └─ blocks
 │       └─ my-block-1
 │          ├─ block.json
 │          ├─ index.js
 │          ├─ edit.js
 │          └─ save.js
 │
 └───── package.json

my-theme
 │   └─ app.js (imported GSAP as a module)
 │
 └───── package.json (it includes GSAP)
```

I have imported GSAP as a module in my theme inside `my-theme/app.js` for theme animations.

The main question is, for use GSAP in a block:

Should I use the GSAP library present in the theme (`my-theme/app.js`) also for blocks? If yes, the plugin will be theme dependent.

Should I include GSAP in the `my-block-1/save.js`?

If yes: It doesn't matter that the GSAP library in the plugin is redundant with the GSAP theme's library?

Also, will the library be loaded every time a block is included in the editor? (Many blocks = many redundant libraries)

**[EDIT]** I have found a third option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70827130/2986401). Enqueue the javascript once in the plugin (not once per block). Also, [here](https://richtabor.com/has-blocks-gutenberg-scripts/), an article to determine if post has a specific block and enqueue conditionally.

Comment: Are you using GSAP in your theme for animations/use outside of this block?

Comment: Exactly, yes. (15 characters)